# How do I find the coordinates for a place on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

When I zoom to a place in the Google Earth Engine Code Editor, how can I find the latitude and longitude as decimal numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Select the `Inspector` tab  on the right panel, then click on the map. You'll see the coordinate of the Point you clicked in the right panel.

[image]